# ningún controlador de dispositivo fue encontrado para instalación de Windows 10

Tags: macos

Buenas (disculpen la traducción de los mensajes tengo mi laptop en ingles).

Tengo una MacbookPro 2011, windows 10 en un DVD y los drivers de bootcamp en un USB.

Entonces, por el modelo de mi laptop, bootcamp no me deja instalar windows 10, entonces yo mismo hice una partición de disco con *Disk Utility* con formato **MS-DOS FAT** (scheme GUID partition map, no me deja cambiarlo en la sección de partición).

Meto el DVD, reinicio la computadora, presiono <kbd>alt/option</kbd>, escoja el icono del disco que dice "windows" y empieza a correr, no hay problema hasta aquí (supongo).

Selecciono el idioma, formato de hora, teclado y cuando le doy click a "**Instalar ahora**" me sale una ventana que dice:

> "un media driver tu computadora necesita esta faltando. esto puede ser
>   un DVD, USAB or disco duro driver...."

y después otra que dice:

> "ningún controlador de dispositivo fue encontrado..."

¿Que debo hacer?

Comment: MS-DOS FAT funciona para versiones anteriores de UEFI (desde Windows 7 creo, hacia atrás)

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero lo siguiente, puesto que yo lo hice en una macbook pro mid 2010:

Desde Mac Osx, consigue un iso de windows 7 e instala desde el ayudante de bootcamp, cuando reinicies, ten tu memoria usb con windows 10 en el puerto y arranca desde ahi, cuando instales windows 10, instala los drivers para windows 7 , en modo de compatibilidad para windows 7

Saludos!